# calling values from a json file like a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Warning: beginner here:

So I am reading in a text file that is in the form of a json file. Since the son file is just like a dictionary I want to address parts of the json like I would a dictionary but I don't know how to do this. This is the little bit of what i have:

code:

```
with open("trump.txt","r") as lines:
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

what this prints:

{"created_at":"Wed Sep 27 01:19:39 +0000 2017","id":912849180741087232,"id_str":"912849180741087232","text":"RT @TheRickWilson: I see the clickservatives are out in force screaming there were special circumstances in AL.\n\nYes, it's because Trump ca\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":66914769,"id_str":"66914769","name":"Kathy","screen_name":"mydoggigi","location":"Earth","url":null,"description":"Love politics, Grandchildren & PSU #StillWithHer #NotMyPresident Blocked by Susan Sarandon, Glenn Greenwald, Joel Osteen and Joe Scarborough!!\ud83d\ude0e #TheResistance","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":5878,"friends_count":5973,"listed_count":143,"favourites_count":110285,"statuses_count":138191,"created_at":"Wed Aug 19 04:55:41 +0000 2009","utc_offset":-14400,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/903412377424732160/NqCfPFiB_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/903412377424732160/NqCfPFiB_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/66914769/1504225271","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Wed Sep 27 01:08:45 +0000 2017","id":912846439964987392,"id_str":"912846439964987392","text":"I see the clickservatives are out in force screaming there were special circumstances in AL.\n\nYes, it's because Trump can't deliver. Sad!","source":"\u003ca href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":19084896,"id_str":"19084896","name":"Rick Wilson","screen_name":"TheRickWilson","location":"Florida and points beyond","url":"http://facebook.com/therickwilson","description":"GOP Media Guy, Dad, Husband, Pilot, Hunter, Writer. I make ads and do politics. Daily Beast columnist. Everything Trump Touches Dies.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":238578,"friends_count":3518,"listed_count":4235,"favourites_count":48094,"statuses_count":250609,"created_at":"Fri Jan 16 20:50:17 +0000 2009","utc_offset":-14400,"time_zone":"America/New_York","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"1A1B1F","profile_background_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/220716353/Firefox_Wallpaper.jpg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/220716353/Firefox_Wallpaper.jpg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"445555","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"252429","profile_text_color":"666666","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/813585115934658560/gnuRozoD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/813585115934658560/gnuRozoD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/19084896/1504722796","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":5,"reply_count":50,"retweet_count":100,"favorite_count":456,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"TheRickWilson","name":"Rick Wilson","id":19084896,"id_str":"19084896","indices":[3,17]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1506475179263"}

so how can i do something as simple as something below in my code?

```
dict["created_at"]="Wed Sep 27 01:19:39 +0000 2017"
```

Comment: that looks like json ... try `import json;json.loads(line)`

Comment: `data = json.load(open('file.json'))`, then `data['created_at']=...`.

Comment: There is no need to try to do it yourself since there are already modules that do it for you. You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that'll fail if JSON contains newlines.

Comment: i couldn't figure out how to import a json file with python3

Comment: @randomir do i just add your line to the code i already have?

Comment: ah yeah when i try to import it as a json file i have been getting this error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 4925)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
#code
```

Comment: it doesn't work i get the error    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 4925)

Comment: That seems like an error with the json code itself.

Comment: yeah i think it was i figured it out but i don't know why that happened. Do you know how to call it if it repeats. as in if I wrote data['created_at'] that is mentioned twice in the json file but when i write that line of code it only prints out the first time.

Comment: wait that code is rejecting duplicates but i want the duplicate

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307068/make-a-dict-json-from-string-with-duplicate-keys-python) should work then.

Comment: like the create_at time is different each time mentioned in the json file so i want all those values