# Counting duplicate JSON keys in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with multiple duplicate keys in the following format:

```
"data": {
    "nameA": {
        "result": someInt,
        "timestamp": "someTime"
    },
    "nameB": {
        "result": someInt,
        "timestamp": "someTime"
    },
    "nameA": {
        "result": someInt,
        "timestamp": "someTime"
    },
    "nameC": {
        "result": someInt,
        "timestamp": "someTime"
    }
}
```

I need to dynamically determine the number of instances of each key and print them out. What would be the best way to accomplish this for a JSON in this format?

Comment: Rather than be concerned with the "best" way, have you found any way to make this work? What are you unhappy about with your current approach?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this question might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321677/python-json-parser-allow-duplicate-keys

Comment: @roganjosh I haven't found an approach that works yet. The JSON default parser updates the dictionary while writing, and only the last entry is stored. So I need a way to catch duplicates while parsing, or find a way to store each individual object within data during the json.loads function

Comment: @SimonBrahan I think that the Counter solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902299/json-loads-allows-duplicate-keys-in-a-dictionary-overwriting-the-first-value) is on the right track, but instead of rejecting the keys, I need to find a way to keep track of each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the answer given to this question: [json.loads allows duplicate keys in a dictionary, overwriting the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902299/json-loads-allows-duplicate-keys-in-a-dictionary-overwriting-the-first-value) , this should work:

```
import json

testjson = '{"data": {"key1": "val", "key2": "val", "key1": "val"}}'


def parse_multimap(ordered_pairs):
    multimap = dict()
    for k, v in ordered_pairs:
        if k in multimap:
            multimap[k].append(v)
        else:
            multimap[k] = [v]
    return multimap

parsed = json.loads(testjson, object_pairs_hook=parse_multimap)

for key in parsed['data'][0]:
    print("Key: {} | Count: {}".format(key, len(parsed['data'][0][key])))
```

**Output:**

```
Key: key2 | Count: 1
Key: key1 | Count: 2
```

Comment: Because your testjson is in a different format as mine, I just get Counter(('data': 1)). How can I get it to look inside "data" before performing this operation?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!