# Matching values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I am trying to match below elements in json data.

```
a={'n_name': 'APP-Ptyh ', 'n_name': 'Com Don Ctes - Aty ', 'n_name': 'Sce Fbh - Dor Node', 'n_name': 'kke gg - Dor Node'}
b={'n_name': 'APP-Ptyh', 'n_name': 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'n_name': 'Sce Fbh - Dor Nomk ', 'n_name': 'kke gg - Dor Node'}
c=[]
```

What I have done to match :

```
if a["n_name"] == b["n_name"]:
   c.append(b["n_name"])
```

This doesn't matched the elements properly as in `a` data source the elements `APP-Ptyh` is same in both but there is a trailing whitespace.
What is expected output is it should match irrespective of trailing white spaces.
Any help on how can I achieve that.
This is the desired output of matched elements t be stored in list `c` :

```
c= ['APP-Ptyh', 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'kke gg - Dor Node']
```

Comment: If those keys are just example, you can use [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the trailing whitespace. `if a["n_name"].strip() == b["n_name"].strip`

Comment: Your dictionaries have duplicate keys, so your if statement will only compare the last elements in dict a and b. Please fix or rename your dictionaries for further help

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902299/json-loads-allows-duplicate-keys-in-a-dictionary-overwriting-the-first-value).

Comment: A dictionary can not have the same key and different value, now what are you going with ```a["n_name"]``` ???

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has duplicated keys, which not suitable. Dictionary must have unique keys (as it refers key). So, you may use the below implementation to your purpose.

**Code:**

```py
a={'n_name': ['APP-Ptyh ', 'Com Don Ctes - Aty ', 'Sce Fbh - Dor Node', 'kke gg - Dor Node']}
b={'n_name': ['APP-Ptyh', 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'Sce Fbh - Dor Nomk ', 'kke gg - Dor Node']}
c=[]

for val in a['n_name']:
    if val in b['n_name']:
        c.append(b["n_name"][b["n_name"].index(val)])
```

**Result:**

```py
['APP-Ptyh', 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'kke gg - Dor Node']
```

This works but not a good time complexity. It is better to give unique keys if would.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dict with duplicate keys. Instead, you can use a single key and, as value, a list of elements that had that key.

So you can follow these steps:

1.See if the current element's (of your initial set) key is in the final dict. If it is, go to step 3

2.Update dict with key

3.Append the new value to the dict[key] list

4.Repeat [1-3]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dictionary keys must be unique.

```
a={'n_name_1': 'APP-Ptyh ', 'n_name_2': 'Com Don Ctes - Aty ', 'n_name_3': 'Sce Fbh - Dor Node', 'n_name': 'kke gg - Dor Node'}
b={'n_name_1': 'APP-Ptyh', 'n_name_2': 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'n_name_3': 'Sce Fbh - Dor Nomk ', 'n_name': 'kke gg - Dor Node'}

def compare_value(key1, key2):
    if key1.strip() == key2.strip():
        return key1.strip()

filter(lambda x: x != None, map(compare_value, a.values(), b.values()))

>>>['APP-Ptyh', 'Com Don Ctes - Aty', 'kke gg - Dor Node']
```