# How to not overwrite index in json.loads

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the followin json and I want to load it in python without overwriting the multiple index:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "HOSTNAME": "test",
      "STATUS": "200",
      "TYPE": "linux",
      "CPU": {
        "SRC": "src",
        "LINK": "link",
        "LABEL": "cpu"
      },
      "CPU": {
        "SRC": "src",
        "LINK": "link",
        "LABEL": "cpu"
      },
      "MEMORY": {
        "SRC": "src",
        "LINK": "link",
        "LABEL": "cpu"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using:

```
 json.loads("HERE COMES THE JSON")
```

The result overwrite the index, example:

```
 {
 data:
     [
     {
      "HOSTNAME": "test",
      "STATUS": "200",
      "TYPE": "linux",
      "CPU": {
             "SRC": "src",
             "LINK": "link",
             "LABEL": "cpu"
             },
      "MEMORY": {
                "SRC": "src",
                "LINK": "link",
                "LABEL": "cpu"
                }
      }
      ]
 }
```

Note that is only one CPU.

Is there any way to not overwrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not valid JSON and you cannot use the `json` module to parse it the way you want to.

**UPDATE:** it seems that it's possible after all with the help of the `object_pairs_hook` parameter to `json.load(s)`; see [SimpleJson handling of same named entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825261/simplejson-handling-of-same-named-entities) for an example.

Comment: I edited, now is a valid, rsrs sorry

Comment: It's invalid JSON because it has repetitive keys—this is not allowed by the JSON specification; anyway, I've provided a link to a solution that works even with your quasi-JSON data.

Comment: "It worked" is usually expressed on Stack Overflow by accepting the question ;)

Comment: Im waiting the time to accept rsrs