# Convert nltk Tree to JSON representation

Tags: python, json, tree, nltk

I would like to convert the following nltk Tree representation into JSON format:

[image: nltk Tree structure]

Desired output:

```
{
    "scores": {
        "filler": [
            [
                "scores"
            ],
            [
                "for"
            ]
        ],
        "extent": [
            "highest"
        ],
        "team": [
            "India"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not a valid JSON: there are two "team" names in the same object. JSON object is an unordered set of name/value pair. Different json parser may produce different results: a parser may preserve only the first 'team', or only the last 'team' pair, or (unlikely) [create a list `["India", "Pakistan"]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7828652/4279)

Comment: See also [rfc 7159](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159): *"When the names within an object are not
   unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
   unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
   only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
   object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
   including duplicates."*

Comment: again the source tree contains duplicate names `('filler', 'filler')` Why do you remove them from the output?

Comment: it got removed automatically while building the dict. Its okay to have them removed since the filler info is not required in the output.

Comment: How do you know that it is not required in the output?

Comment: I mean, it is not required for my use-case. I think your answer is the right one!

Comment: Imagine you are given an arbitrary `nltk.Tree`: how does your code know which nodes exactly it should remove from the tree? What is special about the child `'filler'` nodes that they are removed but the parent `'filler'` node is preserved?

Comment: my input Tree itself has duplicate keys. Hence converting them to dict will be erroneous and unexpected. I need to fix my input Tree to have something like filler1, filler2. Do you know how we can handle recursive feature based grammar? I am having `filler -> filler filler` and `filler -> 'is' | 'are' | 'the' | 'for' | 'by' | 'of'` to accomodate any number sequential unwanted words in my input

Comment: ok. As I understand you should not remove `'filler'` from json output if it is present in the input Tree. You should transform one `nltk.Tree` into another `nltk.Tree` (with collapsed 'filler' nodes) instead. It is unrelated to serializing `nltk.Tree` to json.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the input tree may contain children with the same name. To support the general case, you could convert each `Tree` into a dictionary that maps its name to its children list:

```
from nltk import Tree # $ pip install nltk

def tree2dict(tree):
    return {tree.node: [tree2dict(t)  if isinstance(t, Tree) else t
                        for t in tree]}
```

Example:

```
import json
import sys

tree = Tree('scores',
            [Tree('extent', ['highest']),
             Tree('filler',
                  [Tree('filler', ['scores']),
                   Tree('filler', ['for'])]),
             Tree('team', ['India'])])
d = tree2dict(tree)
json.dump(d, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{
  "scores": [
    {
      "extent": [
        "highest"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "filler": [
        {
          "filler": [
            "scores"
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "filler": [
            "for"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "team": [
        "India"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert Tree to dict and then to JSON.

```
def tree_to_dict(tree):
    tdict = {}
    for t in tree:
        if isinstance(t, nltk.Tree) and isinstance(t[0], nltk.Tree):
            tdict[t.node] = tree_to_dict(t)
        elif isinstance(t, nltk.Tree):
            tdict[t.node] = t[0]
    return tdict

def dict_to_json(dict):
    return json.dumps(dict)

output_json = dict_to_json({tree.node: tree_to_dict(tree)})
```

Comment: convert the `tree` into a `dict` and use `json.dump(result_dict, sys.stdout, indent=2)` instead of generating json text by hand.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it again.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian How to convert tree into dict? which method should I use?

Comment: `t.node` has to be switched to `t.label()` now. for the sentence "Tom Brady plays for the Patriots." the output was: `{'ORGANIZATION': ('Patriots', 'NNP'), 'PERSON': ('Brady', 'NNP')}`

Answer (score 2):

the will covert the tree to a dictionary with the tree labels as the key, then you can convert it into JSON using by using JSON dumps easily

```
    import nltk.tree.Tree

    def tree_to_dict(tree):
        tree_dict = dict()
        leaves = []
        for subtree in tree:
            if type(subtree) == nltk.tree.Tree:
                tree_dict.update(tree_to_dict(subtree))
            else:
                (expression,tag) = subtree
                leaves.append(expression)
        tree_dict[tree.label()] = " ".join(leaves)

        return tree_dict
```

Comment: as a point of comparison, this outputs `{'ORGANIZATION': 'Patriots', 'PERSON': 'Brady', 'S': 'plays for the .'}` for the sentence "Tom Brady Plays for the Patriots."

Answer (score 0):

A related alternative. For my purposes, I didn't need an exact tree preserved, but instead wanted to extract entities as keys and tokens as lists of values. For the sentence "Tom and Larry play for the Patriots." I wanted the following JSON:

```
{
  "PERSON": [
    "Tom",
    "Larry"
  ],
  "ORGANIZATION": [
    "Patriots"
  ]
}
```

This preserves order of tokens (per entity type), while also not "stomping" values set for an entity key. You can reuse the same `json.dump` code in the other answers to return this dict to json.

```
from nltk import tag,chunk,tokenize

def prep(sentence):
    return chunk.ne_chunk(tag.pos_tag(tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)))

t = prep("Tom and Larry play for the Patriots.")

def tree_to_dict(tree):
    tree_dict = dict()
    for st in tree:
        # not everything gets a NE tag,
        # so we can ignore untagged tokens
        # which are stored in tuples
        if isinstance(st, nltk.Tree):
            if st.label() in tree_dict:
                tree_dict[st.label()] = tree_dict[st.label()] + [st[0][0]]
            else:
                tree_dict[st.label()] = [st[0][0]]
    return tree_dict

print(tree_to_dict(t))
# {'PERSON': ['Tom', 'Larry'], 'ORGANIZATION': ['Patriots']}
```